# How to get list of all Azure Tenants

Tags: azure, powershell

When I login to Azure and list all subscriptions I see a list of 9 tenants (see pic).
via this url: https://portal.azure.com/#settings/directory
However when I use Get-AzTentant I only get 4?
How can I programmatically obtain a list of all 9 accessible Tenants?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Look at the picture you posted.  The domain are different. Which domain did you log into?  Which domain(s) did you get the 4 results from?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the access to all the tenants listed in your Azure Directory because the cmdlet `Get-AzTenant` returns the list of tenants if your account is authorized with those tenants as it is mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-aztenant?view=azps-9.2.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-3.2.0#examples).

[image]

I have given the access to only one tenant for one of the users and checked by logging with that user credentials:

[image]

Comment: Hi. I really don't understand. When I go to: https://portal.azure.com/#settings/directory is see 9 tenants that I have access to. When I type Get-AzTenant in PS window I get only one?

Comment: AFAIK, I believe your Microsoft Account should have the Read permissions on other tenants to fetch those details. Still if you're facing any issue, reach out to azcommunity@microsoft.com for assistance.

Comment: Suggest to try Get-AzContext command, to identify the account currently being used by PowerShell session and play from there.